# Azure Functions Java auto generated with scala files

Tags: java, scala, azure-functions

I just used autorest generator https://github.com/Azure/autorest.azure-functions:

```
autorest --azure-functions-java \
         --input-file:./petstore.yaml \
         --output-folder:./generated-azfunctions \
         --namespace:com.company \
         --version:3.0.6320
```

with petstore.yaml from [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/autorest/main/Samples/openapi-v3/1a-code-generation-minimal/petstore.yaml)

it generated code with pom.xml: [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/maciejbak85/69e9a8b7d2cc34478551f634c59cc28a)

I would like to use it but in hybrid mode with scala, scala would contain logic and in java only http layer.
How to do that, is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking exactly. It's possible to mix Java and Scala in a Maven project (more in the way of Scala calling Java but opposite is possible as well). Is it possible in the context of Azure functions? I have no idea.

Comment: Well I upload jar so azure is ready for that, but I dunno how to add to this project scala compiler. So it would work with java and additionally scala. It could be even spring boot app not azure.

Comment: One possibility: https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html

Comment: great - thanks !

Comment: If you have found the answer, you can post an answer so that it might be helpful to other community members who might face the same issue.